# Firewall failure path ignored on second attempt

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

With a firewall `failure_path` set, a user's first failed attempt at login follows the failure path. When the user clicks again on login, a `Bad Credentials` exception is thrown rather than allowing the user to try again.

#### firewall:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            failure_path:    /message/inactive
```

#### login menu link (using KnpMenuBundle)

```
if ('anon.' === $user) {
    $menu->addChild('Sign in', array(
        'route' => 'fos_user_security_login'
    ));
} else {
    $menu->addChild("Sign out", array(
        'route' => 'fos_user_security_logout',
    ));
}
```

Where else should I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the answer: modify security.yml as below:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            failure_path:    /message/inactive
            failure_forward: true
```